# i18n-next Binding not working for deep JSON objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multilingual, i18next

```
// import detector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";
import backend from "i18next-http-backend";
import XHR from 'i18next-xhr-backend';
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";


i18n
  .use(XHR)
  .use(initReactI18next) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
  // .use(backend)
  .init({
    lng: "en",
    fallbackLng: "en",
    ns: ['translations'],
    defaultNS: ['translations'],
    debug: true,
    backend: {
      loadPath: '/i18n/{{ns}}/{{lng}}.json'
    },
    saveMissing: true,
    keySeparator: false, // we do not use keys in form messages.welcome

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
      //formatSeparator: ",", // react already safes from xss
    },
    react: {

      wait: true,
      useSuspense: false

    }
  });

export default i18n;
```

I am trying to translate deep json object but its not working above is the configuration file.
JOSN file looks like below :
{
"test" : "change ut",
"test1" : "abc"
}
Translation : {t(`test`)}
Working correctly.

Now I want some changes in JSON i.e

```
"test" : {
now:"Testing change deeply"
}

Use : {t(`test.now`)}
```

**Output Result : test.now
Desired Output(should be) : Testing change deeply.**

But It's not working somehow.
Any help is truely appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got the answer the only thing that needs to be change is the 'Key-separtor' option in the init.So the finaly initialisation file would be like.

```
i18n
  .use(XHR)
  .use(initReactI18next) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
  // .use(backend)
  .init({
    lng: "en",
    fallbackLng: "en",
    ns: ['translations'],
    defaultNS: ['translations'],
    debug: true,
    backend: {
      loadPath: '/i18n/{{ns}}/{{lng}}.json' // http://localhost:8050/public/i18n/translations/en.json
    },
    saveMissing: true,
    keySeparator: ".", // we do not use keys in form messages.welcome

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
      //formatSeparator: ",", // react already safes from xss
    },
    react: {

      wait: true,
      useSuspense: false

    }
  });

export default i18n;
```

I hope this works for you too @Nabeel Sajid :)

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example for you
***login.json***

```
{
  "welcome_back": "Welcome back!",
  "please_login_your_account": "Please login using your account",
  "username": "USERNAME",
  "password": "PASSWORD",
  "forgot_your_password": "Forgot your password?",
  "login": "Login",
  "reset_here": "Reset Here",
  "create_an_account": "CREATE AN ACCOUNT"
}
```

***i18n.js***

```
import i18n                   from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next }   from "react-i18next";
import login_en         from "./en/login.json";

const resources = {
  en: {
    translation: {
      "login": login_en
    }
  }
};

i18n
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    resources,
    lng: "en",
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false
    }
  });

export default i18n;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reponse but you are using a flat json file I want to use a tree json file. For flat json file its working for me also. In your case try creating tree json i.e something like {"welcome" : {back : "Welcome Back!",again : 'Welcome Again'},"Bye" : {}}
Something like this is not working for me.Thanks